# OnClickListener throws NullPointerException on startActivity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, roboguice

I am using Android API 17 with Android Development Tools (ADT) I have a **Help** buttton which is listening for click event. **HelpButtonListener** is listening for the click event for **Help** button as following:

**Excerpt from MainActivity.java**

```
private final class HelpButtonListener implements OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v) {           
        Intent mainToHelpIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HelpActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainToHelpIntent);        
    }
}
```

Following code for **HelpActivity** works just fine ans shows me **Some helpful stuff..** on `HelpActivity` creation:

```
public class HelpActivity extends RoboActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView helpTextView = new TextView(HelpActivity.this);
        helpTextView.setText("Some helpful stuff..");
        setContentView(helpTextView);
    }
}
```

But if I try to use set the text in the `TextView` view component injected using RoboGuice 2 for inject the `TextView` using the following code, it gives me a `NullPointerException`:

**HelpActivity.java**

```
public class HelpActivity extends RoboActivity {
    @InjectView(R.id.helpTextView)
    private TextView helpTextView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        helpTextView.setText("Some helpful stuff..");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);
    }
}
```

Following is the error I get when I click the Help button and try to set the text in the `TextView` created on `activity_help.xml` layout resource:

```
05-16 18:00:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(9880): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 18:00:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(9880): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wickedlynotsmart.myfirstapp/com.wickedlynotsmart.myfirstapp.activity.HelpActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-16 18:00:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(9880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-16 18:00:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(9880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-16 18:00:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(9880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-16 18:00:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(9880):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-16 18:00:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(9880):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-16 18:00:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(9880):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-16 18:00:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(9880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-16 18:00:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(9880):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 18:00:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(9880):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-16 18:00:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(9880):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-16 18:00:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(9880):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-16 18:00:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(9880):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-16 18:00:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(9880): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-16 18:00:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(9880):     at com.wickedlynotsmart.myfirstapp.activity.HelpActivity.onCreate(HelpActivity.java:22)
05-16 18:00:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(9880):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-16 18:00:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(9880):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-16 18:00:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(9880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-16 18:00:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(9880):     ... 11 more
```

Could someone help me understand why am I getting this error?

Thanks.

Comment: @blackbelt: I added the `super.onCreate` call in the `onCreate` method of `HelpActivity` but it still doesn't work and shows the same `NullPointerException` error.

Comment: @blackbelt: I mistakenly clicked edit to your annwer for when I was wanting to click on comment to comment on your answer, I cancelled the edit and saved and all that I could but I can't see your answer again.

Comment: check my answer and feel free to ask if any questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First set the content to the activity. Then initialize textview. Then set the text to textview. You have not initialized textview. Hence you got NullPointerException.

It should be like:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);
TextView helpTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.helpTextView);
helpTextView.setText("Some helpful stuff..");
```

Comment: Yes in first case you are creating dynamic textview then are you adding it to the view. Yes it will work. But in second case To access the textview or any widget from layout xml file you should first set the xml file in setContentView before reading.

Comment: There is no need this line
TextView helpTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.helpTextView);

RoboActivity take care it

Comment: @Abhi you don't read textview. you intialize the textview. I have edited that part of your answer since it was misleading

Comment: @Raghunandan Thank you. Can you come [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5098/android-people), if not leave this invitation :)

Comment: @Abhi i am blocked by So fro few days I can't chat now. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

// this is link

http://killertilapia.blogspot.in/2012/09/why-u-no-use-roboguice.html
https://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/SimpleExample

```
 public class HelpActivity extends RoboActivity {
 @InjectView(R.id.helpTextView)
 private TextView helpTextView;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);
    helpTextView.setText("Some helpful stuff..");

  }
}
```

Comment: Hello first set setcontent then you will get instance of textview

Comment: Oh dear, what was I doing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You set the content to the activity then initialize your textview by findViewById of the view hierarchy and then set text to textview. Your textview is not initialized hence you get NullPointerException.

```
private TextView helpTextView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_help); //set content tot eh activity
    helpTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview); // initialize textview
    helpTextView.setText("Some helpful stuff.."); //set text to textview

}
```

According to this link https://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/SimpleExample. Using Robospice could be as below.

```
private TextView helpTextView;
@InjectView(R.id.textview)             TextView helpTextView;   
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_help); //set content tot eh activity
    helpTextView.setText("Some helpful stuff.."); //set text to textview

}
```

Comment: It will explain about RoboJuice

http://killertilapia.blogspot.in/2012/09/why-u-no-use-roboguice.html

Comment: @pawanyadav could you explain why this happens coz i have not tried robospice myself

Comment: RoboJuice is google framework and it avoid dependency injection. This link explain in elaborate .

http://www.programmingmobile.com/2011/06/dependency-injection-for-android-with.html